# Changing the state of a checkbox with setState

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a component and i am able to change the state of checkbox item when i click on a button.
I also want to be able to change the state in another button-click, which has lot more logic in it. 
The issue i am having in that when the code goes into the condition it does not set the state back to false.

I tried changing the state again using setstate but it does not change the state of the enabledCheckBox.

```
this.setState({
  enabledCheckBox: !this.state.enabledCheckBox,
})
```

Can anyone tell me what the issue is?
Thanks

```
class Customer extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = {
      ...props,
      enabledCheckBox: false
    };
  }

  //this works    
  onChangeCheckBox=()=>{
    this.setState({
      enabledCheckBox: !this.state.enabledCheckBox,
    })
  }

  //cant get this to work
  handleCustomerClick = (event) => {

    if (this.state.enabledCheckBox) {      
      this.setState({
        enabledCheckBox: !this.state.enabledCheckBox,
      })
    }
```

Comment: Can we see the render method that calls handleCustomerClick?

Comment: Are you sure `handleCustomerClick` is being executed?

Comment: yes i am sure i am calling my handleCustomerClick it goes into the the if statement .

Comment: <Button onClick={this.handleCustomerClick}/>

Comment: hmmm... the error must be somewhere else, i tried a fiddle here and it seems to work : https://jsfiddle.net/69z2wepo/238204/

Comment: thanks for ruling that out as the issue. i will keep debugging and see if i cant find out the issue

Comment: How are you setting the value of checkbox? Is it a connected component or not? If it's not connected (meaning if "checked property <input type='checkbox' checked={this.state.enabledCheckBox}> is not set, it won't matter if you update the state

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your `this` is being bound incorrectly try this;

```
handleCustomerClick = (event) => {
  let {enabledCheckBox} = this.state;

  this.setState({
    enabledCheckBox: !enabledCheckBox,
  });
}
```

If you really need the if statement you could do the following;

```
handleCustomerClick = (event) => {
  let {enabledCheckBox} = this.state;
  let data;

  if (enabledCheckBox) {
    data = {
      enabledCheckBox: !enabledCheckBox
    }
  }

  this.setState(data);
}
```

Comment: why i debug in chrome i can now see the enabledcheckbox value whereas before i was saying undefined. However this doesnt switch the value to false. enablecheckbox stays as true. If i hover over this.setstate i get a message saying cannot read property setstte. i am not sure if this helps. thanks for the help

Comment: Pretty sure what you wrote was the same thing as op's code. Arrow function does have its own `this`. It shares the same `this` where ever you are creating it. So `this` in that case has the same context as `this.state`.

Comment: Hi mark, i done what you suggested and when  i view the code in debug mode it has changed the data ={enabledCheckBox: false} . However when i view the  this.state = {  enabledCheckBox: false  } the value did not change.

Comment: i had an issue with my  componentWillReceiveProps aswell i had this,setState{...this.state} which was missing up my state. Thanks very much for the help

Answer (score 2):

https://codesandbox.io/s/1y0zywy727

I included a working example. It does similar things as how you described.

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";

import "./styles.css";

class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      enabledCheckBox: false
    };
  }

  onClick = () => {
    this.setState({ enabledCheckBox: !this.state.enabledCheckBox });
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <input
          type="checkbox"
          value={"some checked box"}
          checked={this.state.enabledCheckBox}
          onChange={this.onClick}
        />
        {this.state.enabledCheckBox ? <div>Blue</div> : <div>Red</div>}
        <button onClick={this.onClick}>Click to Change Color</button>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<App />, rootElement);
```

Both `input` and `div` are using `this.state.enabledcheckbox`. So if you check the box, not only the box will be checked but also the `div`'s "color" would change with it. Same thing as clicking the `button`

Comment: The issue was to do with the if statement and something else i did. you need to do it the mark did because when its in the if statement it doesnt update correctly